# jQuery performance when appending multiple elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

After I make an AJAX call, I need to iterate over the results, clone a template (it's a div that I use as template for my elements), set its labels using a class selector and then append the new elements to the DOM. Right now I'm appending them all together after the loop to avoid reflows.

One important thing to point out is that the div where I'm appending the elements is hidden and empty while I'm iterating the data I receive from the AJAX call.

It's taking around 3 seconds to render 1,500 elements and it's only text.

This is my code (AJAX call is not included, just the success part of it):

```
var resultsControl = $("#divFollowUpResults");
var template = $("#FollowUpTemplate");
var itemControls = [];

$.each(data, function (i, value) {
  var itemControl = template.clone();
  itemControl.removeAttr("id").show();
  $(".FollowUpDateCreated", itemControl).text(value.DateCreated);
  $(".FollowUpUser", itemControl).text(value.User);
  $(".FollowUpDateOfferId", itemControl).text(value.OfferId);
  $(".lnkOfferId", itemControl).attr("href", $(".lnkOfferId", itemControl).attr("href") + "/" + value.OfferId);
  $(".FollowUpCar", itemControl).html(value.OfferVehicle);
  $(".FollowUpOfferAmountAndType", itemControl).text(value.OfferAmountAndType);
  $(".FollowUpOfferStatus", itemControl).text(value.OfferStatus);
  $(".FollowUpOfferStatusDate", itemControl).text(value.OfferStatusDate);
  $(".FollowUpOfferPostState", itemControl).text(value.OfferPostState);
  $(".FollowUpOfferVIN", itemControl).text(value.OfferVIN);
  $(".FollowUpType", itemControl).text(value.Type);
  $(".FollowUpReason", itemControl).text(value.Reason);
  $(".FollowUpStatus", itemControl).text(value.StatusName);
  $(".FollowUpDate", itemControl).text(value.Date);
  $(".FollowUpPM", itemControl).text(value.Owner);
  $(".OfferSellerName", itemControl).text(value.OfferSellerName);
  $(".OfferSellerAddress", itemControl).text(value.OfferSellerAddress);
  itemControl.attr("data-follow-up-item-id", value.Id);
  itemControl.attr("data-follow-up-item-date", value.DateYYYYMMDDHHmm);
  itemControl.attr("data-follow-up-item-owner", value.Owner);
  itemControl.attr("data-follow-up-item-status", value.StatusName);
  itemControl.attr("data-follow-up-item-status-id", value.StatusId);
  itemControls.push(itemControl);
});

resultsControl.append(itemControls);
resultsControl.show();
$("#divFollowUpSearching").hide();
```

Comment: Try more specific targeting if possible, for example instead of `$(".FollowUpUser")` use `$("#myDiv.FollowUpUser")`

Comment: You're already only modifying the dom once, so the only thing you could possibly do to make it faster would be to cut jquery out of it and instead use a plain text template (or some templating library)

Comment: actually... the `.append(itemControls)` may be appending them one by one(likely is) which could be causing a performance hit too if the browser isn't optimizing the rendering.

Comment: Additionally... 1500 elements... how many results is that? do you really need to display that many results at once?

Comment: I'm not using $(".FollowUpUser"), I'm using $(".FollowUpUser", itemControl) which only selected the element that has the class FollowUpUser for the itemControl element. I read about .append(array) and it should use a document fragment under the hood. The page where I'm working doesn't have paging, that was a business requirement.